# How can I get gmail notifications to start working on a Samsung Galaxy S10+?

Tags: samsung, notifications, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Got a new samsung s10 plus phone and I dont see Gmail notifications. Notifications dont show up anywhere irrespective of being on wifi or phone data.

Things I have done so far :

- Battery optimisation turned off for Gmail
- Adaptive battery - cycled between all available modes.
- Notifications turned on for Gmail (Settings -> Notifications)
- All gmail app notifications turned on within the app (Gmail -> Settings -> Notifications)
- "special access" > optimize battery usage > turn of the gmail app (which I believe is the battery optimisation option anyway)
- S10 settings > Apps > GMail > Mobile Data and enabled "Allow background data usage" and "Allow app while data saver is on"

The phone has the latest software and is up to date. I have followed the discussions on the top 5 google results of "gmail notifications not working on S10 plus" and haven't been able to find a solution. I am hoping I can find some help here.

Comment: Did you try clearing data of the app? (Settings > apps > gmail > clear data)

Comment: @aBochur - That did it !!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my new s10, and the clear data didn't work.

I had to dig in the settings to find it out that when turning the power save mode, it disables the auto syncronization.

You can manually turn sync back in the setting menu when you swipe down from the top. and preserve the power save mode.

Such easy thing but it left me several days without notifications.

Hopefully helps, and saves someone else's time.